# Why dynamic bootstrap popover not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, popover

```
    $('body').popover({html: true, placement: 'left', trigger: 'hover', selector: "[rel='popover']"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zxEXz/

I just insert 'selector' option for dynamic popover.
but, another options('html', 'placement ') not working.

It's just using wrong or bootstrap bug??

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is looking like a bug in the bootstrap

Internally bootstrap is using the following code inside the method `enter` in tooltip.js

```
this._options && $.each(this._options, function (key, value) {
    if (defaults[key] != value) options[key] = value
}, this)
```

we are passing 3 parameters to the each method, the object, callback, and `this`

where as if you look at jQuery code for [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method, it says that the `args` parameter is only for internal use and it is not documented.

```
// args is for internal usage only
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
```

If you remove `this` from the each call it might work... :(

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R2LS5/)

It is most probably a minor mistake happened because the [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) takes a second parameter which will be uses as the execution context for the callback method... in jQuery it should have been done using [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) like

```
this._options && $.each(this._options, $.proxy(function (key, value) {
    if (defaults[key] != value) options[key] = value
}, this))
```

In the [master branch](https://raw.github.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/js/tooltip.js), this bug seems to have got fixed

```
this._options && $.each(this._options, function (key, value) {
  if (defaults[key] != value) options[key] = value
})
```